# Scraping an embedded PowerBI table with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Trying to scrape data from an embedded PowerBI Table with Selenium.

The table is available over here https://textileexchange.org/find-certified-company/

After the PowerBI table loads, I would like to click on the Search Button
[image: Button to click on]

After clicking on the button, I would like to scrape all the data within the table, as well as click on each entry and click on the Get details button to go to the next page and scrape the data on the second page as well. If anyone is able to help or point me towards the right direction, that will be much appreciated!

However, my code doesn't seem to work as it is blocked.

```
from selenium import webdriver as selenium_webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

# Set up the selenium webdriver
driver = selenium_webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get('https://textileexchange.org/find-certified-company/')

# Wait for the PowerBI table to load
time.sleep(10)

# Switch to the iframe
iframe = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@id='powerbi-embedded-26880']//iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Find the search button and click it
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Search']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_button)

# Wait for the results to load
time.sleep(3) 

# Find all cells
cells = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pivotTableCellWrap')

# Initialize an empty list to hold the rows
rows = []

# Initialize an empty list to hold the current row
row = []

# Iterate over the cells
for cell in cells:
    # Get the column index of the cell
    column_index = int(cell.get_attribute('column-index'))

    # If the column index is 0, this is the start of a new row
    if column_index == 0:
        # If there is a current row, add it to the rows
        if row:
            rows.append(row)

        # Start a new row
        row = [cell.text]
    else:
        # Otherwise, add the cell to the current row
        row.append(cell.text)

# Add the last row to the rows
if row:
    rows.append(row)

# Convert the rows to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

# Close the driver
driver.quit()
```